Approximation of the Set of LQR feedbacks for parameter-varying system matrix
Consider the classical continuous-time LQR case with infinite control horizon.
One entry of the system matrix $A$ is represented through the scalar parameter $a\in[\underline{a},\overline{a}]=\mathcal{A}$.
It is assumed that $(A(a),B)$ is stabilizable and $(A(a),\sqrt{Q})$ is detectable for all $a\in\mathcal{A}$.
The optimal feedback $K(a)=-R^{-1}B^T P(a)$ is typically calculated via Riccati Matrix $P\succ 0$ which solves the Algebraic Riccati Equation (CARE) $A^T P(a) + P(a)A - P(a)BR^{-1}B^T P(a) +Q =0$.
The set all optimal feedbacks is denoted by $\mathcal{K}:=\{K(a), a\in\mathcal{A} \}$.
I want to "overestimate" the set $\mathcal{K}$  with a n-sphere $\mathcal{C}$ such that $\mathcal{K}\subset \mathcal{C}$.
Hence, I formulated the following optimization problem
$$  \begin{align}  \min_{r,\hat{K}}~ &  r \\ \text{s.t. } & r^2\geq \Vert K-\hat{K}\Vert^2 ~ \forall K\in\mathcal{K} \\ & r > 0 \end{align}  $$
to calculate the center $\hat{K}$ and the minimal radius $r$ of $\mathcal{C}$.
How can I reformulate the optimization problem such that a solver can handle the problem with infinite constraints?
Some additional information:

I assume that the map $f:a\to K(a)$ is continuous (and unique) under the assumptions, but I couldn't prove it
The problem is a semi-infinite program (SIP).
The feedback $K(a)= -R^{-1}B^T P(a)$ can be easily calculated via the SDP
$$ \begin{align*}
        \max_P ~& \operatorname{tr }(P) \\
        \text{s.t.}& \begin{bmatrix} A^T  P + P A +Q & PB \\ B^T P & R  \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 \\        & P \succeq 0 
    \end{align*}$$
I am able to formulate the KKT conditions for that SDP. The complementary slackness conditions are nonconvex quadratic equalities.
I guess that the discretization of $\mathcal{A}$ is not useful, since I want to guarantee that $\mathcal{K}\subset \mathcal{C} $.


That's an interesting question.
